# How to tell Vim about the end of a comment

Tags: vim, comments

Vim has a feature where it automatically inserts a comment prefix on a new line if the previous comment line is too long and is wrapped. It also inserts the newline prefix if you press Enter. This makes it easy to type long comments, but inconvenient when you want to end the comment. You have to hit backspace to remove the comment prefix on the last line.

Is it possible to modify Vim so that if I hit Enter only at the last line, it knows to terminate the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be controlled by [`formatoptions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table).  From the linked documentation page

> 'formatoptions' is a string that can contain any of the letters below.
>      **...**
>   t   Auto-wrap text using textwidth
>   c   Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting the current comment leader automatically.
>   r   Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting Enter in Insert mode.
>   o   Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or 'O' in Normal mode.
>   **...**

This means that you want `c`, but not `r` and presumably not `o`. A bare example line in `.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType bash,csh setlocal formatoptions=c
```

You need to have `textwidth` set elsewhere (for example `set textwidth=72`).

See the continuation of the linked page for far more.  If you have a string of letters there already then just remove `r` and `o` from it. A related option is [`comments`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27comments%27) -- see [format-comments](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#format-comments) page.

Answer (score 0):

How will Vim know what you intend the last line to be?

The only workaround I can think of is binding to the `InsertLeave` autocommand to clear the line if it's just a comment character:

```
autocmd InsertLeave * if getline('.') =~ '^# *$' | normal! 0D | endif
```

However, it will also remove the comment character on lines such as:

```
# Hello, world
#
# Continuing with the next paragraph
```

Improvements that can be made:

- Parse `&comments` to get the comment character − see [`:help format-comments`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#format%2dcomments) for the format.
- Only remove the line if the next line doesn't start with a comment character.
- You could possibly map `<Cr>` in insert mode to do something similar this so you don't have to leave insert mode − be very careful with this, though, since you may end of removing more than you want!
- My recommendation: just press backspace.